# JSON parsing: show data on UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json

This is the given [API](http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/search.json?status=fundraising) that I have to parse.I also have to show the name on my `UITableView`. I want to fetch the value of name n show it on table view.
This is the code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [ episodes count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[ episodes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"names"];


    return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UIAlertView *logoutConfirm = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Toilet Finder" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Display on Map",@"Route",@"Cancel", nil];
    logoutConfirm.tag = 111;
    [logoutConfirm show];

}

- (void) parseJSONWithURL:(NSURL *) jsonURL

{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
 dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSError *error = nil;
     NSString *json = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:jsonURL
                                               encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
     if (error == nil){
         WebInServe=@"http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/search.json?status=fundraising";
        NSLog(@"URL %@", WebInServe);
         NSURL *Final_Url = [NSURL URLWithString:WebInServe];

         NSData*   jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: Final_Url];


         NSError* error;

         jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
         NSLog(@"What is contain let me check %@",jsonDict);
         NSArray* latestLoans = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"loans"];

         NSLog(@"loans in array: %@", latestLoans);


          episodes = [[jsonDict valueForKey:@"latestLoans"]valueForKey:@"name"];


                 if (error == nil)
         {
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
                  episodes = [[jsonDict valueForKey:@"latestLoans"]valueForKey:@"name"];
                 [tableView reloadData];
             });
         }
```

I have tried using:

```
episodes = [[jsonDict valueForKey:@"latestLoans"]objectForKey:@"name"];
```

I have used several tymes `objectForKey` and `valueForkey` but in the above code and in the

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[ episodes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"names"];
```

line of code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath: method`

but the data is not displayed on tableview...indeed it is displayed on `NSLog`...

Comment: Check this tutorial : http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why using `dispatch_queues` instead of using the dedicated async API of `NSURLConnection`?

As explained in Apple's Concurrency Programming Guide, when there already is a dedicated API to execute some task in a concurrent manner, avoid to make your own concurrent version by wrapping a synchronous call (like `+[NSString stringWithContentOfURL:]` in your case) inside asynchronous queues (like `dispatch_async` on a concurrent queue in your case).

---

Moreover, your `latestLoans` variable (which you then `NSLog`) extracts its content from a key called `@"loans"`, but in the next line when you try to extract the episodes, you extract it from the dictionary assumed to be associated to a `@"latestLoans"` key. There is probably some discrepancy in your code there, isn't it? **That's probably your main problem in your code.**

---

And finally sometimes you use `valueForKey:` (which is a generic Key-Value-Coding method that works using introspection, not at all a dedicated `NSDictionary`-specific method) instead of `objectForKey:` (which is what you need to use when accessing objects from an `NSDictionary`).

Sure `valueForKey:` will work but `objectForKey:` being the dedicated method for `NSDictionary` it will be more efficient.
Personally I even prefer the new "Objective-C Modern notation" for Object Literals, namely `dict[key]` that the compiler will translate to `objectForKey:` automatically for you (this `[]` notation is only some syntaxic sugar to be more concise)

So here comes my code suggestion:

```
...
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse* resp, NSData* jsonData, NSError* err) {
  ...
  NSDictionary* jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
  NSArray* latestLoans = jsonDict[@"loans"];
  self.episodes = latestLoans[@"name"];
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is here:

> episodes = [[jsonDict valueForKey:@"latestLoans"]valueForKey:@"name"];

The root of the JSON response has only two items - "paging" and "loans". You are asking for "latestLoans". Since there is no such item in the root level of the JSON, you will get nil in episodes.
I think you should use the call you performed for the logging:

> NSArray* latestLoans = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"loans"];

Try with

> episodes = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"loans"];

instead of

> episodes = [[jsonDict valueForKey:@"latestLoans"]valueForKey:@"name"];